# Dojo DateTextBox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dijit.form

I am trying to implement dojo date. I am trying [example](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html#changing-constraints-on-the-fly) from official website, but it does not work. Am I missing something here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: false}</script>
    <script src="resources/js/dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
        require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/DateTextBox"]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
    <input data-dojo-id="myFromDate" type="text" name="fromDate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" required="true"
           onChange="myToDate.constraints.min = arguments[0];"/>
    <label for="toDate">To:</label>
    <input data-dojo-id="myToDate" type="text" name="toDate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" required="true"
           onChange="myFromDate.constraints.max = arguments[0];"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your error, but the *for* attribute of a *label* element should reference an ID, not a name.

Comment: I actually don't use those label elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code in the `dojoconfig` you are specifying  that the `parseOnload` to false , so the HTML  will not be parsed as a `dijit` component.

The solution is to set it to true ( `call parser.parse())` or create the callback function in the require section as below :

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/DateTextBox"],function(parser,data){
    parser.parse();
});
```

then , for the style you have to import a [dojo css theme](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/themes.html) and add it's class the `body` tag , in the below code I'm using `[claro][2]` theme so I've add the to the body it's class `=>` `<body class="claro">`

Example 1 : you can test the above complete example using `parseOnload:true` :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: true}</script>
    <script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
      require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/DateTextBox"]);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
    <div>
      <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
      <input data-dojo-id="myFromDate" type="text" name="fromDate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" required="true"
             onChange="myToDate.constraints.min = arguments[0];"/>
      <label for="toDate">To:</label>
      <input data-dojo-id="myToDate" type="text" name="toDate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" required="true"
             onChange="myFromDate.constraints.max = arguments[0];"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example 2 : by setting `parseOnload:false` and using callback function + `parser.parse()`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: false}</script>
    <script  src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
    <script>
        require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/form/DateTextBox"],function(parser,data){
         parser.parse();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
 <div>
     <label for="fromDate">From:</label>
     <input data-dojo-id="myFromDate" type="text" name="fromDate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" required="true"
            onChange="myToDate.constraints.min = arguments[0];"/>
     <label for="toDate">To:</label>
     <input data-dojo-id="myToDate" type="text" name="toDate" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" required="true"
            onChange="myFromDate.constraints.max = arguments[0];"/>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's all .

Comment: I finally understood how to use dojo properly. Thank you for your awesome answer!